# How to split a string by underscore and extract an element as a variable in bash?

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a string such  like `s=DNA128533_mutect2_filtered.vcf.gz`. How could I extract the `DNA128533` as an ID variable.

I tried

```
id=(cut -d_ -f1 <<< ${s}
echo $id
```

It seems not working. some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It seems like that your syntax is incomplete, it should be `id=$(cut -d_ -f1 <<< "$s")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to start a shell to run cut etc when you can use builtins

```
s=DNA128533_mutect2_filtered.vcf.gz
id=${s%%_*}
echo $id
DNA128533
```